# Using Angular2 services as directives (for ngIf)

Tags: angular

I am trying to change the behaviours of my nav-bar component in Angular2, based on whether a user is logged in or not (an exported param in my user Service). I have just set isLoggedIn to return true for this. Unfortunately, the link isn't displaying, as:

> angular2.js:23730 EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on UserService

I use UserService as a regular service in other places in the app, can I make it so it can also be used as a directive, without interfering with any of its other functionality?

nav.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';

import { UserService } from '../user/services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  template: `
  <div class="nav">
    <a [routerLink]="['LoginComponent']" *ngIf="UserService.isLoggedIn">Login</a>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['client/dev/todo/styles/todo.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, UserService],
  providers: [  ]
})

export class NavComponent {}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from 'angular2/core';
import { Headers, Http } from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor(@Inject(Http) private _http: Http) {
    this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    //return this.loggedIn;
    return true;
  }
}
```

## UPDATE:

Also, if I move the service to providers rather than directives, then the component doesn't display at all, error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined in [UserService.isLoggedIn in NavComponent@2:41]

So it would seem I can't reference that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're injecting your service in your `directives` property, therefore is expecting a `@Component` or a `@Directive`.

```
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, UserService], // <<< Not good! Remove it from there!
```

You have to inject in in your `providers` property

```
providers : [UserService] /// Good!
```

**Edit**

So your question is more like *Can I use a Service as a Directive?*, the answer would be no. You would have to annotate your Service with `@Component` or `@Directive` and by that time it wouldn't be a simple service anymore.

Comment: If I keep all the code the same, but move UserService to providers, then my nav component doesn't display?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards at this point I can't guess what's wrong, you'll need to provide a plnkr reproducing your issue, or adding more info to your question. Since this is a service you should be injecting it in the component constructor and I don't see that in the code.